# Relation between the difference of the vector and its scales

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, functional-analysis, inequality

Let $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$. I want to know whether it is true that
$$|x-y|<r \text{ iff } |x_i -y_i|<r.$$

My attempt:
Assume that $|x_i-y_i|<r$ for all $1\leq i\leq d.$ Then,$$ \sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^{2}+\ldots+(x_d -y_d)^2} \leq
|x_1-y_1| +\ldots+|x_d-y_d|< \frac{d}{r}.$$

It seems it is not, but on the other hand, all distances are equivalent, which implies that the statement is true.

Comment: Possibly you could replace $(x-y)$ with $a\in\mathbb R^d$ and each $(x_i-y_i)$ with $a_i$...? This would simplify the notation WLOG.

Comment: What do you think that "equivalent distances" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a counter-example in two dimensions, choosing $x$ to be the origin. Here is the unit circle (i.e. $r=1$) and $y$ in the first quadrant:

[image]

Comment: A picture worth a thousand words. :) Superb!